# Why does Mathematica WolframScript get file fail?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I use Mathematica 11 and create a project containing two files: a package file named `MyPackage.m` and the other named `run.m`.The package file contains just normal functions not in special Mathematica package structure (https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/packages.html) and the other contains code to get `MyPackage.m` and use the functions.

```
(* Package.m *)
myFun[x_String] := Print[x]
...

(* run.m *)
<<"Package.m"
myFun["Hello,World"]
```

I put these two files into one directory and ensure that the `$path` contains the directory path. But, when I run `wolframscript -file ./run.m -print all`, it complains `$Failed`.
The question is: how to import another file when using wolframscript? It seems cannot find the destination file even they are in the same directory.

I use Mathematica 11 and run wolframscript in Ubuntu server where I have installed the latest Free CDF Player.

Comment: suggest you ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I encountered no problem running your script.  Also, `-print all` appears to be superfluous.

```
C:\Users\chrisd\Documents\test>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 102A-B66B

 Directory of C:\Users\chrisd\Documents\test

14/09/2017  15:03    <DIR>          .
14/09/2017  15:03    <DIR>          ..
14/09/2017  14:59                29 Package.m
14/09/2017  14:59                38 run.m
               2 File(s)             67 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  215,590,776,832 bytes free

C:\Users\chrisd\Documents\test>wolframscript -file run.m -print all
Hello,World

C:\Users\chrisd\Documents\test>type Package.m
myFun[x_String] := Print[x]

C:\Users\chrisd\Documents\test>type run.m
<<"Package.m"
myFun["Hello,World"];

C:\Users\chrisd\Documents\test>
```

Comment: Do you install Mathematica in your machine or just CDF Player? I can run the script without problem if the full-pack Mathematica installed, but fail when just `CDF Player`  installed. I think `free CDF Player` may not support running script this way.

Comment: @hliu I expect that would be the case.